# Подскажите легковесную библиотеку для работы с картинками в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

прошу подсказать легковесную и простую библиотеку JS для работы с Canvas.
Чтобы можно было в canvas добавлять свои картинки любого размера и текст, не теряя качество картинки такого плана.

Пример, как должна примерно выглядеть картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А просто в canvas без библиотеки с картинками работать как-то проблемно?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev падает качество картинки и текста

Comment: При изменении размера картинки качество в любом случае будет падать, потому что пиксели уже не идентичные. А если картинку вставлять прошлых размеров, то будет идентично. Вам какой-то особенный метод сглаживания нужен?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я делаю размер канваса под размер картинки, но проблема еще с добавлением текста. почему то он тоже превращается в пиксели

Comment: @PavelGrishaev хочу сделать, чтоб выглядело точно так же https://media.rabota.ru/og_image/vacancy/3/43712211.png

Comment: Но когда на канвасе рисуешь текст, то по умолчанию у него есть сглаживание. Вот например - https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_stroketext

Comment: @PavelGrishaev нашел интересную штуку window.devicePixelRatio. ее значение умножить на ширину и высоту канваса. в итоге рисуется изображение нужного качества

Comment: У вас так просто сам канвас становится размером видимо попадающим в пиксели на экране. Потому что канвас и так рисует текст сглаженным и чётким. С картинками у него бывают проблемы сглаживания, но частично их можно решить если в начале установить `context.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";` и затем рисовать картинки.

Comment: наверное, к тэгу `canvas` применяются css стили `width` `height`?